# TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, typescript

When the login is success I try to redirect other page in this case I have used a demo page index.html on sucess. But $location.path is not redirecting to the new page. I get the error as TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined.

```
module LoginModule {
    export class LoginController {
        username: string;
        password: string;
        static $inject = ['$http','$location'];
        constructor(private $http : ng.IHttpService,private $location : ng.ILocationService){
        }
        login() {
            this.$http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'https://localhost:8061/nada/login',
                data : $.param({'username' : this.username, 'password' : this.password}),
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                }}).success(function(data) {
                    this.$location.path("/success");
                   //alert("sucess");
                }).error(function(error) {
                    JSON.parse(error);
                    alert('No access available.');
                   // console.log(result);
                });
        }
    }

    angular.module('loginModule', ['ngRoute']).controller('LoginController', LoginModule.LoginController).config(['$routeProvider' ,function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when("/", {
            templateUrl: 'html/login.html'
        })

        .when("/success", {
            templateUrl: 'html/index.html',
            controller: 'clientsController'
        })
        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});

    }]);

}
```

Is there something missing in my code. Also I have placed the routing part in the .config method can I move it to a class as I am trying to do it in typescript, if so how can I access that in mycontroller.

I have login page that accepts the username and password. And makes a rest call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to preserve lexical scope in your success handler in order to utilize `this` as the context of your class by using a fat-arrow function...

```
}}).success(function(data) {
                this.$location.path("/success");
```

will need to be:

```
}}).success((data) => {
                this.$location.path("/success");
```

Fat-arrow functions are your friend **=>**

Comment: Thanks for ur reply that problem is solved, but now it appends sucess to my url. https://localhost:8061/html/login.html#/success. I want it to redirect to html/index.html

Comment: @AjinkyaKhavare i'm confused then... `this.$location.path("/succuss")` is supposed to append /success to the url. This answer solved your problem, you now have a new problem of your code doesn't do what you want it to do. I think you have a mis-understanding of how angular works.

Comment: I agree with @KevinB if this solved your issue about the undefined value, mark it as answered and work to solve your `$location.path` issue on your own. And if you have an issue/question with that, please post another question